# handling race conditions error prone code with sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, race-condition, optimistic-locking

i'm trying to create a very small project so i can practice sequelize.
Basically i have Users, Products, Categories and Purchases.

- Users can buy at most 3 products
- User can't buy the same product more than once.
- Each Product belongs to a Category

And i want to mantain, with code, three aggregate counters:

- spentMoney and purchaseCount (for User)
- productCount (for Category)

I'm aware of options like simple queries, triggers, views, etc for aggregate ops. I just want to practice sequelize.

So, i did it and as far as i understand, it works.
My question is about methods: **createProduct** and **registerProductPurchase**. Are those prone to race conditions? I don't think so because i'm using version number and transactions.
Inside **createProduct** i'm checking for version number of Category, and inside **registerProductPurchase** for version number of User. Both of them are loaded at the beginning of transaction.

createProduct maps to this sql:

```sql
Executing (9136e456-63f0-4753-98eb-a28099b0d881): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (9136e456-63f0-4753-98eb-a28099b0d881): SELECT "id", "name", "productCount", "version" FROM "categories" AS "ProductCategory" WHERE "ProductCategory"."id" = 2;
Executing (9136e456-63f0-4753-98eb-a28099b0d881): INSERT INTO "products" ("id","name","price","categoryId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id","name","price","categoryId";
Executing (default): UPDATE "categories" SET "productCount"=$1,"version"=$2 WHERE "id" = $3 AND "version" = $4
Executing (9136e456-63f0-4753-98eb-a28099b0d881): COMMIT;
```

and registerProductPurchase maps to this:

```sql
Executing (54fa334a-fe94-4686-88ee-6c6ed6ceddbd): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (54fa334a-fe94-4686-88ee-6c6ed6ceddbd): SELECT "id", "name", "price", "categoryId" FROM "products" AS "Product" WHERE "Product"."id" = 2;
Executing (54fa334a-fe94-4686-88ee-6c6ed6ceddbd): SELECT "id", "email", "spentMoney", "purchaseCount", "version" FROM "users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = 2;
Executing (54fa334a-fe94-4686-88ee-6c6ed6ceddbd): SELECT "purchaseDate", "userId", "productId" FROM "purchases" AS "Purchase" WHERE "Purchase"."productId" = 2 AND "Purchase"."userId" IN (2);
Executing (54fa334a-fe94-4686-88ee-6c6ed6ceddbd): INSERT INTO "purchases" ("userId","productId") VALUES (2,2) RETURNING "purchaseDate","userId","productId";
Executing (54fa334a-fe94-4686-88ee-6c6ed6ceddbd): UPDATE "users" SET "spentMoney"=$1,"purchaseCount"=$2,"version"=$3 WHERE "id" = $4 AND "version" = $5
Executing (54fa334a-fe94-4686-88ee-6c6ed6ceddbd): COMMIT;
```

which seems fine to me.

This is the code (the relevant part. i'm also using express )
**If there exist race conditions in my code, how could i test for it?**

```js
var sequelize = require("sequelize")

const db = new sequelize.Sequelize('postgres://root:root@localhost:5432/catalog')

var Category = db.define('ProductCategory', {

    id: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true

    },
    name: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    productCount: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: 0
    }

}, {
    version: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'categories',
    modelName: 'ProductCategory'
});

var Product = db.define('Product', {

    id: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true

    },
    name: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false

    },
    price: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false

    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'products',
    modelName: 'Product'
});

var User = db.define('User', {

    id: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true

    },
    email: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    spentMoney: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    purchaseCount: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0
    }
}, {
    version: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'users',
    modelName: 'User'
});

var Purchase = db.define('Purchase', {
    purchaseDate: {
        type: sequelize.DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    version: false,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'purchases',
    modelName: 'Purchase'
});

Category.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: "categoryId" })
Product.belongsTo(Category, { foreignKey: "categoryId" })

Product.belongsToMany(User, { through: Purchase, foreignKey: "userId" })
User.belongsToMany(Product, { through: Purchase, foreignKey: "productId" })


Category.prototype.incrementProductCount = async function(options) {

    this.productCount += 1

    return await this.save(options)

}

User.prototype.buy = async function(product, options) {

    if (this.purchaseCount === 3)
        throw new Error("User can't buy more than 3 products")

    try {

        await this.addProduct(product, options)

    } catch (err) {

        if (err instanceof UniqueConstraintError) {
            throw new Error("User already bought product " + p.id)
        }

        throw err

    }

    this.spentMoney += product.price
    this.purchaseCount += 1

    await this.save(options)


}

async function createProduct(categoryId, productInfo) {

    let t

    try {

        t = await db.transaction()

        let category = await Category.findByPk(categoryId, { transaction: t })

        let product = await Product
            .build({...productInfo, categoryId: categoryId })
            .save({ transaction: t })

        await category.incrementProductCount({ transaction: t })

        await t.commit()

        return product

    } catch (error) {

        if (t)
            await t.rollback()

        throw err


    }

}

async function registerProductPurchase(userId, productId) {

    let t

    try {

        t = await db.transaction()

        let product = await Product.findByPk(productId, { transaction: t })

        let user = await User.findByPk(userId, { transaction: t })

        await user.buy(product, { transaction: t })

        await t.commit()

    } catch (error) {

        if (t)
            await t.rollback()

        throw error


    }

}
```

Comment: At least you don't use a transaction in `incrementProductCount`.

Comment: @Anatoly check line: await category.incrementProductCount({ transaction: t })

Comment: Exactly! You pass it but don't use it in `incrementProductCount`: `function()` and `this.save()`

Comment: @Anatoly you're right. Done.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I've tested it and it works. You could get rid of custom methods like "buy" and handle that logic inside of service class. But, it would be the same.
Also, you could implement retry logic for OptimisticLockError if needed (but that was not the original question)